# Windows Home Server Passwords Do Not Match

Tags: windows-home-server

I have a Windows Home Server that chunks along just fine most of the time. I've never bothered to put it on a UPS and so it's vulnerable to power outages that happen a few times a year. This most recent time, it came back and seemed to be fine, but whenever I try to access a shared folder I get "Passwords do not match". They matched before the power went out, and I couldn't update the WHS password since I apparently didn't know the old one. How do I fix this?

(I asked this on ServerFault and they recommended it be asked here instead)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the power outage had caused the system clock to reset itself back to 2010. Once I reset it to the correct time the errors went away.